# Select random object in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a AWS S3 bucket containing around ~10,000 image objects. I want to use `boto3` to randomly get an object. `list_objects_v2()` only lists 1,000 objects at a time but allows you to paginate. My question is if the method I currently am thinking of doing this is the best way to do it. I was going to paginate through each list of objects saving all the keys in each page to a list. After there are no more pages left, randomly select a key from the list.

Comment: While that method will work is there any other way to generate the key to the object in S3? I guess it depends on how often you have to regenerate the list but you're describing a bit of an expensive operation.  But if, for example, you knew that the file names were all `IMG` + [0-9999] + `.jpg` or whatever, you could generate the keys without reading the list.  Just a thought.

Comment: @stdunbar The problem I see with that is that while I do know all of the file names but after I access an object I'm deleting it from the bucket. So I would have to keep track of the files I already accessed.

Comment: You have a second problem, @IsiahL. (The first: this will be slow and cost too much.)  You cannot assume that a deleted object will *immediately* disappear from subsequent list-objects results.  You may want to consider explaining *why* you want to pick a random object and then delete it.  You may be overlooking other concerns, as well.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot So basically this is just a personal fun project to make a twitter bot that tweets a picture every 2 hours or so. I planned to use Lambda to do the work for the low cost and low amount of work and it only made sense to me to use S3 to store the pictures. If you have a better method please let me know!

Comment: @IsiahL it makes sense for S3 to store and serve the pictures. It doesn't make sense for S3 to randomly select them though. You need to store a list of the pictures somewhere else, in a form that can be easily queried randomly. It's a very common pattern to store files on S3 but store references to them in a database or cache or search engine.

Comment: @MarkB That's what I'm now understanding, I'm going to attempt your answer below. I've never used Redis before but there's never a better time to learn than during personal projects!

Answer (score 4):

If you know the object keys  (filenames), then it is an easy problem to solve. Even if you do not know the filenames ahead, you can build a list of objects by paginating through `list_objects_v2()`.

Keep a list of filenames, shuffle it and pop one by one.

```
import random

mykeys = [objj1, obj2, ....] # or build this list by paginating
random.shuffle(mykeys)
while mykeys:
  random_key = mykeys.pop()
  print random_key
```

Another option is to use `random.choice`

```
import random

mykeys = [objj1, obj2, ....] # or build this list by paginating
while mykeys:
  random_key = random.choice(mykeys)
  mykeys.remove(random_key)
  print random_key
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to delete each object after you have randomly selected it I would pre-load all object keys in a ElastiCache Redis cache. This will give you a [fast method of retrieving a random key](https://redis.io/commands/randomkey). This will many times faster than the boto3 call to S3 you are proposing, will be safe for use with multiple concurrent processes, and you can be sure that once you remove a key from Redis it won't be returned in subsequent calls (unlike S3).

Comment: If I'm reading it right the ElastiCache node is always running? Is there anyway to start and stop it in my lambda process? I don't want to have to pay a lot for this project and running it 24/7 for a couple seconds every couple hours seems unnecessary.

Comment: ElastiCache requires a server and I don't think it can be stopped. You could instead run a Redis server on an EC2 instance and stop/start it when needed. You would have be sure to configure Redis to persist the database though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you also need to keep the Accessed State, you can use a DynamoDB table that keeps track of the metadata of files.

- You can create a item in Dynamodb using S3 triggers and Lambda.
- For the attributes, select the S3 Key (file name) as the Hash key,  normal attribute to store a Flag to track whether its accessed or not, and another attribute to store a Random number.
- Create a GSI using a Random number as the Hash key and Accessed Flag as the range key.
- In your query you only need to generate a Random number within its range and do a query with Accessed Flag is false. If an item is returned you can update the Flag as true. If not query again generating a new random number.
- Here its important to select a proper range of the Random numbers (e.g 1 to 2 or 1 to 5 or 1 to 10) to reduce the average number of retries you are hoping to do for a query.